# Stop IntentService from inside my application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm building some kind of chat program that uses GCM to notify the user that a message is available. I followed the gcm client example using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `IntentService` and everything works as expected.

The `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

and the `IntentService`:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "IOAN";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification(extras.getString("sender"), extras.getString("message"));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
   //... more stuff
}
```

So the `IntentService` sends a notification to my application.

Now, when the user closes my application (back button -> are you sure you want to exit? -> yes), I want to also have a check box "do you still want to receive messages?" (or something like that), and if the user chooses not to receive messages, I want to stop the service that handles the gcm message and restart it when the app runs again.

How do I do that?

Edit: I tried `stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GcmIntentService.class));` but I still get the notifications.

Edit 2: Seems like a `boolean` value in `SharedPreferences` works fine... any better solution?

Comment: call **context.stopService(intent)** whenever you want to stop your service..

Comment: @kalyanpvs I tried stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GcmIntentService.class)); but I still get the notifications.

Comment: @ioan Boolean in `SharedPreferences` is the correct solution. The reason for that being that OS after receiving the GCM notification sends an intent to your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` which wakes up the service again. So correct way of handling this is to ignore this in `GcmIntentService` by checking the `boolean` from `SharedPreferences`. Other solutions might be to either register/unregister brodcast receiver but that is in my opinion too much work, so better to just keep a `boolean` to ignore. Another solution is to disable notifications from server side (which in my opinion is a good thing).